# Windows 10: How do you find the actual location of programs in the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I'm trying to convert svg images to png from the command line. I know I can do that using inkscape. But I can't run it because I can't figure out where it is.

If I open the start menu and type it, it finds it immediately, and I have it pinned to the start menu, but there doesn't seem to be any hint to where the file is actually located. I can right click some of the other files and select more>>open file location, but it's not an option on Inkscape.

I've copied a shortcut from there, which seems to be linking to something called `25415Inkscape.Inkscape_9waqn51p1ttv2!!INKSCAPE` or something like that, but it won't show me the full link. I've tried running it from the shortcut, but command line arguments don't seem to work. I have found a folder called `25415Inkscape.Inkscape_9waqn51p1ttv2`, but it doesn't seem to have an exe file for it.

Should I just uninstall inkscape and reinstall it, and hopefully keep track of the location this time?

Comment: As Gantendo states, you have it installed through the MS Store as an "app". If you want more control over the files, easiest is to *uninstall* from MS Store and reinstall *directly from the developer*. https://inkscape.org/ It's safe and free, either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default installation directory for InkScape is `C:\Program Files\Inkscape` or `C:\Program Files (86)\Inkscape` for the x86 version.

If you installed it via the Microsoft Store it is probably in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. It is probably hidden. To check hidden items, open This PC, click View and select Hidden items. To obtain the permission: Double-click WindowsApps, go to Continue > security tab > Advanced > Change. Enter the current account name in the pop-up window and click OK.

Another option is to start InkScape, then go to the Task Manager. Look for inkscape.exe in the Processes tab. Right-click it, then chose `Open file location`.